# page title not available with jest/enzyme for testing react app, how to get the title?

Tags: html, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I have created a react app using create-react-app which has produced the barebones of a react app, its pretty good!  I now want to change the title of the page (in index.html) and then test this. I'm using enzyme to test individual components and thats also great but it only gives the html produced from the component.  How can I test the page/dom, specifically the title of the page?

```
it('renders App', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  const title = 'test'
  console.log(global.window.document.title)
  expect(wrapper.contains(title)).toEqual(true);
});
```

global.window.document.title is empty

Comment: you can get the window thru the global object, `global.window.document.title` should work.

Comment: updated question

Comment: do you have to change the title in index.html? you can just do that code in your app component

Comment: As its static, not a spa, this would be the preferred way.  and just to know how to do it as well would be good

Answer (score 1):

1. You can set the title inside your component/App.js in `render()` or `componentDidMount()` as

   ```
   document.title = 'titlename'
   ```

   And check that title here `expect(global.window.document.title).toBe('titlename')`. Worked for me!
2. Try using `react-helmet`. Then check with

   ```
   wrapper.find(Helmet).prop("title")).toEqual('titlename');
   ```